# Connection between two blockchains

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, oracles, connections, sidechain

I am looking for an approach to creating a connection between two blockchain-networks. 
I found out that I can use oracles to get data from extern systems (= second blockchain-network). But how can I proof the data (=trust) in the first blockchain-network from the second blockchain-network?
Are there specific approaches for this?

Comment: You've tagged this with private-blockchain - are they both proof-of-work chains where you don't know who the validators are or does one or both of them have know validators?

Comment: the first private blockchain is Ethereum; the second private blockchain is not a proof-of-work chain, and I don't know the validators

Comment: You will at a minimum need a secure way of getting the blockhash transferred between chains. This can be done via some trusted oracle, or via a SPV system, like btc relay. Once you have a blockhash, all the rest of the data can be easily validated via merkle proofs